# Existence of $v$ such that $f_i(v) = \delta_{i j} $

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

Let $f_1,...,f_m \in V^*$ be a linearly independent family ,and F a field. Show that for each $1\leq j\leq m$ there is a $v\in V$ such that $ f_i (v)=  \delta_{i j} $ for any $1\leq j\leq m$

I thought about defining a linear map $T: V\to F^m$  such that  $T(v) = (f_1(v),...,f_m(v)) $ and proving that T is surjective  using the fact that T is surjective $ \iff Ker(T^t) = 0$ where $T^t$ is the transpose of T.
Is it the right way to do it?

Ps: The exercise doesn't say anything about the dimension of V

Comment: This works in infinite dimensions too. Are you assuming $V$ is finite-dimensional? If not, are you comfortable with the notion of codimension?

Comment: I am not assuming V finite dimensional, I have seen the definition of codimension as dim (V/W)

Comment: The obvious problem is that you have to be kind of careful about defining the transpose of a linear operator between infinite-dimensional vector spaces.